# A slow postgres query on Heroku is not being interrupted by rack-timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, rack

I haven't had much luck finding info via google, maybe someone here has had a similar issue.

We have a rails app running on Heroku with a Postgres DB. We have a particularly slow query (yes, we're working on fixing the query), but in the course of debugging this problem, I observed that our rack-timeout gem is not killing the request at 15 seconds. I've done a side-test via inserting a sleep(50) and sure enough, rack-timeout is working correctly in that case.

Here is a redacted copy of our logs showing that rack-time (time's up!) is happening minutes later and we're still seeing the H12 Request Timeout after 30 seconds.

```
    2011-12-14T21:15:16+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&terms=foo" for 173.164.186.205 at Wed Dec 14 13:15:16 -0800 2011
    2011-12-14T21:15:16+00:00 app[web.2]: search query elapsed time => [0.000365018844604492]
    2011-12-14T21:15:46+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET /search dyno=web.2 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
    2011-12-14T21:18:47+00:00 app[postgres]: [6-1] [removed] [COBALT] LOG:  duration: 211241.725 ms  statement: SELECT  [truncated]
    2011-12-14T21:18:47+00:00 app[web.2]: 
    2011-12-14T21:18:47+00:00 app[web.2]: ActionView::Template::Error (Timeout::Error: time's up!: SELECT  [truncated]):
```

Any insight into why and how to enforce the rack-timeout?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what's happening here is what I call a zombie dyno.  The 30 second timeout is ocurring in the routing mesh which sits above your Dyno.  In theory, your dyno can run for hours, but the user will see an error after 30 seconds directly from the routing mesh.

So. what's happening is this:

1. Your request is made at `21:15:16`
2. At `21:15:46` the routing mesh returns it's error, but your dyno is still processing
3. At `21:18:47` your request finishes.

As for whats happening with Rack::Timeout and your long running query, it maybe down to the pg gem your using as Rack::Timeout is reliant on threads to function correctly. This explains why you get the timeout the moment the database returns.

More info on zombie dynos: http://neilmiddleton.com/avoiding-zombie-dynos-with-heroku/

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I am looking for is insight into how I can force rack-timeout to cut the request off. We're using heroku and we do not specify the pg_gem, heroku does. We're using a non-shared database which is at version 9.0.6.

Comment: Unfortunately Rack Timeout can't kill a running query.  Your application will be using the pg gem on Heroku as it's injected by the slug compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

Until postgres 9.2 comes out (which has a better timeout system), there's not an easy solution with the rack-timeout gem - postgres only checks for connection interruption between statements and thus rack-timeout is somewhat limited in this regard. Its hands are tied... If you had superuser access to postgres you might be able to try some config tweaks, but since you're on heroku, that's not an option.

Try to optimize your database calls (make sure all your indexes are there, etc), or break apart your single statements into smaller chunks for this specific issue (this may seem counter-intuitive).